# NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED in Chrome version 61

Tags: google-chrome, web, ssl-certificate

I see NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED privacy error if I try to open my site https://bonalink.hopto.org/ . I use WoSign CA Free SSL Certificate G2 https://buy.wosign.com/free/?lan=en#ssl in my site. I know, Google to Completely Ban WoSign, StartCom Certificates in Chrome 61 http://www.securityweek.com/google-completely-ban-wosign-startcom-certificates-chrome-61 . Can you tell me any way to resolwing of my problem? Do you know any free certificate authority whan compatible with Chrome 61?

Comment: [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**Free or Self-Signed SSL Certificates** are not the solution which every website admin looking for, as they both come up with many drawbacks.

**Its important to study their drawbacks before using them**

**Self-signed Certificate** is only available for the testing purpose and only works in user's own system, it will not work on any other system as the root certificate will be missing there.

**Free SSL certificate** will work with every web browser if the Certificate Authority is recognized by the browser. But, it will only remain active for some shortest interval of **30-60-90 days** **(depends on CA).** After that, the certificate will remain inactive (expired) and there will be an error for unsecured connection. You need to install the certificate again-and-again-and-again. Waste of time I think.

Your website is totally chat based where the users will share their personal, sensitive and confidential information, If the SSL turns inactive, there will be a big risk of information getting stolen. This could decrease your website's reputation over the internet.

The better alternative is to pay some bucks of money on SSL Certificate. Multiple re-sellers are available which offers SSL at lowest price with heavy discount rates. You should contact any of them.

Comment: Can you tell me link to Free SSL certificate, and re-sellers which offers SSL at lowest price with heavy discount rates?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't recommend using free SSL certificates, [Comodo](https://ssl.comodo.com/free-ssl-certificate.php) is probably the option with most compatibility across different browsers.

If you want to fix ERR_CERT_REVOKED for a particular user, you can disable certificate revocation in the browser settings. For Chrome, this setting is not available because OCSP is disabled by default ([source](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH246030.html)). You may try disabling it in IE and Firefox. For IE:

1. Open **Internet Explorer**
2. In the **Tools** menu, select **Internet Options**
3. Go to the **Advanced** tab. Scroll down to the **Security** section
4. Uncheck **Check for server certificate revocation** option
5. Click **OK**

[image]

([Source](https://port135.com/2019/02/09/error_internet_sec_cert_revoked/))

For Firefox:

[image]